# How to change the content shown in the drawer menu in android studio application when I click on a menu item?

Tags: android, menu, submenu, navigation-drawer

I have to build a menu drawer submenu but I really dont know how to do that, and I haven't found any information about it. The drawer menu has to work this way: when I click on a menu item in the drawer navigation menu, it directs the user to a new drawer menu with new options. the main drawer menu already is built. but I really dont know how to build this sub drawer menu with new options and how to make an action option happen when the user clicks on a submenu item. could you help me with it?

how to direct the user to a new menu(a submenu) when the user clicks on a main menu item?

how to create those submenus?

how to set the action of each sub menu item(how to add the ifs and where to add)?

```js
//here's the main menu onNavigationItemSelected
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
             //here I have to open a new menu drawer
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_grade1) {
            //here I have to open another new menu drawer
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_grade2){
            //open another submenu
            } 
            else if (id == R.id.nav_grade3){
            //open another submenu
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_shapes){
            //open another submenu
            }
            }
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you meant by "direct to a new drawer menu"

If you say a submenu that shows below the menu when clicked, that is a case.

NavigationView has a add submenu() method that can do something if you mean it.

There is a reference that you can look up to.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#addSubMenu(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)